# How can we call the controls from one form to another form of the same application

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I have two forms in C# Window application as **frm_Stock.cs** and **frm_Purchase.cs**.
I want to use some controls of frm_Stock in the frm_Purchase.Is it possible?IF yes then how can i do this please give me suitable example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you have asked 6 questions and never accepted any answer, I won't waste time with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass a reference to the controls/form when constructing the other form, and use that reference.  A rough example,

```
frm_Stock = new StockForm();
frm_Purchase = new PurchaseForm(frm_Stock);
```

then within the purchase form code...

```
public class PurchaseForm : Form
{
  public PurchaseForm(StockForm frm_Stock)
  {
    frm_Stock.SomeControl.Text = "blah";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but not recommended way of doing it, you should have pass it to the other form via some shared object(i-e StateBag ). You can make the controls of Frm_Stock public and then they will be accsible from frm _Purchase when you make frm_Stock instance.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a [custom user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207.aspx) and use it on both forms.

If you want to share the same instance of the user control across the form, then create an instance when your application starts and add it manually on both forms when they load.